# Make logstash input file configurable

Tags: logstash

I have a logstash agent running well :
my config file contains an input file with the path to my folder and it send all the data to my elasticsearch database.

But I would like to make my agent more "advanced". I would like to have a external config file or anything else, where you can specify a path or a list of paths of the logs folders you want to parse, and logstash parse it automatically when it runs.

Basically, is it possible to have a config like this:

```
input
{
  path=>external parameter given by the user (example : "c:/users/xxxx/*.log")
}
```

The goal of this is to don't have to write manually by opening the config file an new input file with the recquired path.

Comment: You can write your own script/program to generate configuration dynamically.

Comment: I wrote the following solution : I have an xml file with the list of logs folders path. I have a batch file which parse the file and generate dynamically a input.config file with each input{file{path=>parameter}}.